# chdir function is not working with relative paths for a discord.py cog

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I am developing a discord bot, based on discord.py version 1.5.0 and I'm facing a problem with os.chdir function.

**Context:** I'm using a cog that requires a json file to read data from. The json file and the cog file are in the same folder, still I have to use function.

**What I've tried yet:**

1. Using without the chdir function, gives the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'repsystem.json'`
2. Moving the json file in a data file *inside* the cog file, and using './data' as the path, gives the error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: './data'`
3. Not using chdir entirely and using the relative path in the open function like `open("./repsystem.json","r")` and it gives the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './repsystem.json'`
4. Moving the json file in the main directory, outside the cogs folder and using `open("../repsystem.json","r")` and it gives the same error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './repsystem.json'`

**Snippets:**
This is the directory, rep.py cog uses the repsystem.json file and

[image]

[This is the entire cog](https://pastebin.com/iRZv6Jga)

Comment: Try `print(os.getcwd())` before and after the `chdir` call, to check that your actual current directory is what you think it is.

Comment: From the screenshot it seems that `repsystem.json` is on the same level as `cogs`, i.e. it is _not inside_ the `cogs` directory.

Comment: myrmica, before checking your answer, I gave '.' as a path, and it worked, even though the repsystem.json file was not in the cog folder. As for the screenshot, I took it when I tried moving it outside the cog folder, besides the main file, it was originally in the cogs folder, my fault on that part. Although, I still have no clue why it wasn't taking './cogs' as a suitable path when it was fine with '.'